# MultiIndex and operations between particular groups in pandas and missing values

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following one-column table indexed by pairs (A, B):

```
       Value
A  B        
a1 b1      1
   b2      3
a2 b1     10
   b2     30
a3 b1    100
```

For a particular value of B, like b2, I would like to get a table that lists all its values together with an extra column that gives the difference between b2 and b1 if the corresponding value for b1 or b2 exists. So the result should be:

```
      b2  b2-b1
a1   3.0    2.0
a2  30.0   20.0
a3   NaN    NaN
a4  40.0    NaN
```

where NaN in both columns for a3 tells that values for both b1 and b2 are missing while NaN for a4 tells that only b1 is missing.

Initially I tried the solution based on [Calculation between groups in a Pandas multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292944/calculation-between-groups-in-a-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('a1', 'b1'), 
    ('a1', 'b2'), 
    ('a2', 'b1'),
    ('a2', 'b2'),
    ('a2', 'b3'),
    ('a3', 'b1'),
    ('a4', 'b2'),
], names=['A', 'B'])

table = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1,3, 10, 30, 31, 100, 40]}, index=index)
tmp = pd.concat([table, table.groupby(level='A')['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.loc[:, 'b2'] - x.loc[:, 'b1'])], axis=1)

b2 = tmp.groupby(level='B').get_group('b2')
b2.index = b2.index.droplevel(level='B')

print(b2)
```

But that gives a table without the a3 row (column names can be fixed with renames):

```
    Value  Value
A               
a1      3    2.0
a2     30   20.0
a4     40    NaN
```

The reason for this is that it seems the transform preserves the original index and the extra NaN are not inserted into the table, right? Is it possible to fix this?

So I tried an alternative with explicit diff between columns in groups:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('a1', 'b1'), 
    ('a1', 'b2'), 
    ('a2', 'b1'),
    ('a2', 'b2'),
    ('a3', 'b1'),
    ('a4', 'b2'),
], names=['A', 'B'])

input_table = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1,3, 10, 30, 100, 40]}, index=index)

grouped = input_table.groupby(level='B')
b1 = grouped.get_group('b1')
b1.index = b1.index.droplevel(level='B')

b2 = grouped.get_group('b2')
b2.index = b2.index.droplevel(level='B')
b2 = b2.rename(columns={'Value': 'b2'})

b2 = pd.concat([b2, b2['b2'] - b1['Value']], axis=1)
b2.rename(columns={0: 'b2-b1'}, inplace=True)

print(b2)
```

This works but it seems rather complicated with all that code to drop levels so the diff between columns work and separated column renames. 
Is it possible to make it simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unstack` to get `B` onto columns and `assign` to create `b2-b1` and `drop` to remove unneeded columns.

```
In [1120]: table.unstack()['Value'].assign(b2b1=lambda x: x.b2-x.b1).drop(['b1', 'b3'], 1)
Out[1120]:
B     b2  b2b1
A
a1   3.0   2.0
a2  30.0  20.0
a3   NaN   NaN
a4  40.0   NaN
```

To get rid of index names use `rename_axis`

```
In [1123]: (table.unstack()['Value'].assign(b2b1=lambda x: x.b2-x.b1).drop(['b1', 'b3'], 1)
                 .rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1))
Out[1123]:
      b2  b2b1
a1   3.0   2.0
a2  30.0  20.0
a3   NaN   NaN
a4  40.0   NaN
```

---

Or, you can store the `unstack` result

```
In [1127]: dff = table.unstack()['Value'].rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)

In [1128]: dff['b2-b1'] = dff['b2'] - dff['b1']

In [1129]: dff
Out[1129]:
       b1    b2    b3  b2-b1
a1    1.0   3.0   NaN    2.0
a2   10.0  30.0  31.0   20.0
a3  100.0   NaN   NaN    NaN
a4    NaN  40.0   NaN    NaN

In [1189]: dff[['b1', 'b2-b1']]  # get specific columns
Out[1189]:
       b1  b2-b1
a1    1.0    2.0
a2   10.0   20.0
a3  100.0    NaN
a4    NaN    NaN
```

---

Details

```
In [1124]: table.unstack()
Out[1124]:
    Value
B      b1    b2    b3
A
a1    1.0   3.0   NaN
a2   10.0  30.0  31.0
a3  100.0   NaN   NaN
a4    NaN  40.0   NaN
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid hardcoding the names of columns to drop? I.e. drop all but 'b1' columns? In my case the table can potentially have quite a few B values.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got the usability of unstack :)